# Short magical realism story that starts out with a boy sitting near the sea (?)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, magic

Off the top of my head: the boy has psychic abilities or the ability to sense if people are in trouble far away. He grows up in the story to become a man. In the end he uses his powers to save someone in a house. I'm not sure but I think they were an orphan too, and lived with their aunt (or something)

Comment: If you've found what you were looking for please add it as an answer rather than vandalising your post. See [answer] for help.